# Detecting breach of unique constraint in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Because `Country.name` in the following code sample has `unique=True`, and because two countries of the same name are created, I'm expecting that `session.commit()` would fail.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


Base = declarative_base()


class Country(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'countries'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(64), unique=True, nullable=False, index=True)


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///countries_example.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

malta1 = Country(name='Malta')
malta2 = Country(name='Malta')
session.add(malta1)
session.add(malta2)
session.commit()
```

But the commit proceeds just fine. How do I detect that the unique constraint was breached?

Comment: Have you perhaps created the DB before adding `unique=True` to your model? If so you have to migrate the DB schema one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code as written, it does fail:

```py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "so4.py", line 26, in <module>
        session.commit()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 906, in commit
        self.transaction.commit()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 461, in commit
        self._prepare_impl()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 441, in _prepare_impl
        self.session.flush()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2177, in flush
        self._flush(objects)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2297, in _flush
        transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
        compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 187, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2261, in _flush
        flush_context.execute()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 389, in execute
        rec.execute(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 548, in execute
        uow
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 181, in save_obj
        mapper, table, insert)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 835, in _emit_insert_statements
        execute(statement, params)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 945, in execute
        return meth(self, multiparams, params)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
        return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
        compiled_sql, distilled_params
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
        context)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception
        exc_info
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
        reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 186, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
        context)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
        cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: countries.name [SQL: 'INSERT INTO countries (name) VALUES (?)'] [parameters: ('Malta',)]
```

The unique constraint is part of the table, not necessarily the model.  When I run the database creation first without it, then run your code, I get no problems.

For a more complicated table, you would want to use a migration tool like alembic, but for this, you could go ahead and do it yourself (you can do it in one script, but I just do two to keep it simple, sorry if that's not pythonic:

```py
    from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    
    
    Base = declarative_base()
    
    
    class Country(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'countries'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        name = Column(String(64), unique=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    
    class TempCountry(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'temp_countries'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        name = Column(String(64), nullable=False, index=True)
    
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///countries_example.db')
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = DBSession()
    
    for country in session.query(Country).all():
        if len(session.query(TempCountry).filter_by(name=country.name).all()) == 0:
            temp_country = TempCountry(id=country.id, name=country.name)
            session.add(temp_country)
            session.commit()
    
    Country.__table__.drop(engine)
    session.commit()
```

followed by

```py
    from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    
    
    Base = declarative_base()
    
    
    class Country(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'countries'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        name = Column(String(64), unique=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    
    class TempCountry(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'temp_countries'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        name = Column(String(64), nullable=False, index=True)
    
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///countries_example.db')
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = DBSession()
    
    for temp_country in session.query(TempCountry).all():
        country = Country(id=country.id, name=country.name)
        session.add(country)
    
    session.commit()

    TempCountry.__table__.drop(engine)
    session.commit()
```

You don't have to pass the id, but you can if you need to keep it for whatever reason.  Also, remember to commit before dropping the table or it won't work quite right.